# Avoid Daylight Saving Time in calculating weeks in between

Tags: time, java-8, jodatime, dst

I'm trying to calculate the number of weeks in between 2 dates.

Using Java SE8

```
public long weekInBetween(Date date1, Date date2)
{
    return ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()),
            date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
}
```

Using Joda Time

```
public int weekInBetween(Date date1, Date date2)
{
    DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(date1);
    DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(date2);
    return Weeks.weeksBetween(dateTime1.toLocalDateTime(), dateTime2.toLocalDateTime()).getWeeks();
}
```

However, whenever it passes a DST start date, i.e. March 11. The time is pushed forward 1 hour, i.e. the date from UTC-8 becomes UTC-7. Therefore, the number of week in between is not correct, 1 week early than expected.

For example, `date1` is `Mon Feb 05 08:00:00 UTC 2018` and `date2` is `Mon Mar 12 07:00:00 UTC 2018`, the number of weeks returns 4 which is technically logical in this case but I want to consider only the date and ignore the time and result to be 5 weeks. How can I do that?

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## java.time

You can transform the [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) with the method [toLocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDate--) using the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

```
date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

This way the time information is erased since LocalDate doesn't store the time, just the date.

About the "time is pushed forward 1 hour", if you are refering that this happends when you use `toInstant()`, that is normal (if your system time zone is UTC + 1), because instant only 'knows' UTC + 0. But when to use `atZone` it should change to your system time zone again, and then the time is 'truncated'.

## Joda-Time

For [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), you could aso use the [toLocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDate--) method instead [toLocalDateTime](http://joda-http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDateTime--).

```
dateTime1.toLocalDate();
```

Or [withTimeAtStartOfDay](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--)

```
dateTime1.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```